# WCF channel timed out error

Tags: wcf

I have devloped an application which connects the database thrugh WCF + LINQ. I am able invoke the service from my asp.net application successfuly. But the problem here is that, when i navigate from end to end in my application almost after four or five clicks, i am getting the late response and says channel timed out error.

If anyone is aware about the soltion for this. It would be really helpful for me.

Thanks,

Comment: What type of binding do you use on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Since it works for the first requests, this may be caused by connections not being closed.

If you make a connection to a WCF service and do not close it, it will remain open until it times out.

The default number of WCF connections limit is 10, and the default timeout is 1 min.

So if you make 10 requests quickly, then the 11th will be refused.